# Create n groups from a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file with the following structure

| Name | Position |
| --- | --- |
| Albert | Producer |
| John | Director |
| Anna | Volunteer |
| Gaston | Tech |
| other 51 names | other 51 positions |

I need to create random groups where each group has one member from each position.
There are only four positions across the dataset.
The final result would be something like

| Name | Position | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Albert | Producer | Group 1 |
| John | Director | Group 1 |
| Anna | Volunteer | Group 1 |
| Gaston | Tech | Group 1 |
| Martin | Producer | Group 2 |
| Vanessa | Director | Group 2 |
| Charles | Volunteer | Group 2 |
| Milan | Tech | Group 2 |

What is the most efficient way to create these groups?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `df.groupby('Position').cumcount()` might be all you need, but then the question becomes how to deal with groups that might not be full, if say you only have 3 directors, but 40 Techs

Comment: Do the positions are always in the same order? I mean if the Producer is in the first position of a group, you can dispatch your groups with this key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `groupby`. One to shuffle the Positions using `sample(frac=1)`, and the other to assign the groups:

```
(df.groupby('Position').pipe(lambda d: d.sample(frac=1))
   .assign(Group=lambda d: d.groupby('Position').cumcount().add(1))
   .sort_values(by=['Group', 'Position']) # optional
)
```

example output:

```
      Name   Position  Group
1     John   Director      1
4   Martin   Producer      1
3   Gaston       Tech      1
6  Charles  Volunteer      1
5  Vanessa   Director      2
0   Albert   Producer      2
7    Milan       Tech      2
2     Anna  Volunteer      2
```

Comment: This works in principle, @mozway, and thank you for that.  However running it on the real dataset returns 5 elements on Group 1 instead of 4.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Or the (anonymized) dataset?

Comment: here you are https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRwoOS37CAe0Mli8gP9hXAXEdT9If4t6hNzJvtby8XMnZy0hvOq5llp0-_W8F5NRznbzZ97DPW-018P/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv

Comment: @JorgeGomes I don't reproduce your issue, I only have groups with 4 positions or less. However I noticed that `"Production "` has a trailing space, be sure to remove them as a word with or without space will be treated differently by python